# how to remove leading and trailing non-alphabetic characters in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to remove any leading and trailing non-alphabetic character in my string.

for eg. `":----- pt-br:-"` ,  i want `"pt-br"`

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
result = subject.gsub(/\A[\d_\W]+|[\d_\W]+\Z/, '')
```

will remove non-letters from the start and end of the string.

`\A` and `\Z` anchor the regex at the start/end of the string (`^`/`$` would also match after/before a newline which is probably not what you want - but that might not matter in this case);

`[\d_\W]+` matches one or more digits, the underscore or anything else that is not an alphanumeric character, leaving only letters.

`|` is the alternation operator.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby 1.9.1 :

```
":----- pt-br:-".partition( /[a-zA-Z](...)[a-zA-Z]/ )[1]
```

partition searches the pattern in the string and returns the part before it, the match, and the part after it.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = subject.gsub(/^[^a-zA-Z]+/, '').gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]+$/, '')
```

Comment: It will still fail if the string contains newlines (or non-ASCII letters).

Comment: I suppose it would, yours is better, hehe.